# css image positioning center

Tags: html, css, css-position

i have problem with positioning image

```
<div class="foto img-thumbnail">
  <img class="img-thumbnail tengah" src="member/37/foto_profile/profile37.png">
</div>
```

the css file

```
.foto {
background-image: url('member/37/foto_profile/large.jpeg');
height: 300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position: 
center center;
width: 100%;
}
.tengah {
position: absolute;
}
```

[image: preview]

**GREEN** = *class* **tengah**

**RED** = *class* **foto**

i want the image (RED) positioning center of div

when i change css like

```
.tengah {
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
position: absolute;
}
```

it returning the center of image
[image: preview1]

anybody can help me?

thanks before :)

Comment: Is the tengah image a defined width and height?

Comment: no, the tengah width image 60px : 60px

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want here?  Do you want to center the red div itself, or center the green one inside the red one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're talking about centering the `.tengah` div in the `.foto`.

If so, then you need:

```
.foto {
  background-image: url('member/37/foto_profile/large.jpeg');
  height: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: 
  center center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

.tengah {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px; /* ADDED */
  margin-left: -30px; /* ADDED */
}
```

The margins are half the width and height of the `<div>` you want centered.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner method that will adapt to different size screens would be to avoid the "position:absolute" altogether by setting auto margins left and right for the .tengah class:

```
.tengah {
   position: relative;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   top: 50%;
}
```

This style class will auto center the image/div. The "top" can be adjusted a little depending on the image length if "vertical-align" is not used.